# how to concat knockout value in combobox

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, combobox

this is the javascript

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.vehicles = ko.observableArray([{
        Id: 1,
        Brand: "Volkswagen",
        Type: "Golf"
    }, {
        Id: 2,
        Brand: "Volkswagen",
        Type: "Sharan"
    }, {
        Id: 3,
        Brand: "BMW",
        Type: "118i"
    }, {
        Id: 2,
        Brand: "BMW",
        Type: "525D"
    }]);

    self.brands = ko.computed(function(){
        var list = ko.utils.arrayMap(self.vehicles(), function(item){
            return item.Brand;
        });

        return ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues(list);
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());

$("select").multiselect();
```

and this is the Html with knockout

```
<select data-bind="foreach: brands" multiple="multiple" >
    <optgroup data-bind="attr: {label: $data}, foreach: $parent.vehicles">
    <!-- ko if: Brand == $parent -->
        <option data-bind="text: Type"></option>
    <!-- /ko -->
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

How do i concat the  `{Brand}/{Id} + {type} .`

http://jsfiddle.net/ruchan/ARF29/2/

Comment: i have tried using templates, but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use JavaScript string concatenation operator `+` in your binding:

```
<option data-bind="text: Brand + '/' + Id + ' ' + Type"></option>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3bSKZ/).

Comment: thanks, that worked. also can you help me use jquery ui combobox  to it?